# Почему не происходит спавн объектов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("ДЕГРАДАЦИЯ")

x = 50
y = 400
weight = 40
height = 60
speed = 5

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

lastMove = "right"

bullets = []

class snaryad():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

def drawWindow():
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 500:
            if bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
        lastMove = "left"
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
        lastMove = "left"
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - weight - 5:
        x += speed
        lastMove = "right"
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 500 - weight - 5:
        x += speed
        lastMove = "right"
    if not isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            if jumpCount < 0:
                y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    if keys[pygame.K_f]:
        if lastMove == "right":
            facing = 1
        else:
            facing = -1
        if len(bullets) < 3:
            bullets.append(snaryad(round(x + weight / 2), round(y + height / 2), 5, (255, 0, 0), facing))

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, weight, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Я хочу добавить в игру стрельбу при нажатии на кнопку F

```
if keys [pygame.K_f]:
        if lastMove == "right":
            facing = 1
        else:
            facing = -1
        if len(bullets) < 3:
            bullets.append(snaryad(round(x + weight / 2), round(y + height / 2), 5, (255, 0, 0), facing))
```

но при нажатии f почему-то ничего не происходит, помогите исправить код

Comment: Старайтесь более подробно писать проблему, заголовков вопросов это тоже касается :) Кст, не ставьте пробелы перед операторами `[]`, это сбивает с толку, `if keys [pygame.K_f]:` очень похоже на опечатку с `if keys in [pygame.K_f]:`, т.е. оформляйте как `keys[pygame.K_f]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не отрисовываются пули потому что вы их не рисуете, посмотрите в метод 
`drawWindow()`.

Решение простое:

```
win.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, weight, height))
drawWindow()
pygame.display.update()
```